# Column's alias is ignored with QueryDSL

Tags: java, querydsl

I am trying use alias with QueryDSL projection, but It is ignored

```
Projections.bean(User.class, u.name, u.username, u.email, u.id, r.name.as("role"));
```

The query generated is:

```
select users.name, users.username, users.email, users.id, roles.name from ...
```

I need that "roles.name" be generated as "roles.name as role"

Any idea?

Comment: Do you get an exception without that alias? The alias is used to map to a property in the Bean projection mapping.

Comment: Not, I don't get a exeception. All work fine, but the value it not mapping to bean.

In the bean, the propertie its "role", but the value is null.